# @Singleton on @BindsInstance

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I noticed that Dagger doesn't throw an error when I put the @Singleton annotation on a @BindsInstance method. Does this annotation have any effect there considering that Dagger doesn't create these instances anyways?

Answer (score 2):

No, the annotation doesn't have any behavioral effect: When using `@BindsInstance` the instance returned by the binding will always be the same with or without a scope annotation.

However, Dagger may still check that the binding marked with a scope annotation is properly installed in a matching component—that is, a component that it itself marked with the same scope annotation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Are the only places where `@Singleton` has an effect the component itself, class declarations with `@Inject` constructors, `@Provides` and `@Binds` methods? Am I missing anything?

Comment: @FlorianWalther You can also scope-annotate `@ContributesAndroidInjector` for dagger.android, but that's just syntactic sugar for annotating the subcomponent generated for your Android object. Other than that (and the ones you listed), I can't think of anywhere else you'd see a meaningful scope annotation.